# Why is change in Gibbs free energy not always zero? ($q = T \Delta S$)

Tags: thermodynamics

We know that ,

$ \Delta G = \Delta H - T \Delta S$

We know that $ \Delta H =  q = T \Delta S$

so,

$\Delta G = 0$

Where is my mistake here?

Comment: the formulas are for the *change* in Gibbs free energy yet the title talks about the value of the Gibbs free energy - which do you mean?

Comment: yeah made the question more accurate

Comment: Essentially answered here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/218068/why-is-gibbs-free-energy-not-equal-to-0-its-definition-itself-makes-it-0

Comment: It is close but the thing is that in that answer he explains why it doesn't work in that case. I am trying to find the reason why it would work in the general case compared to that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change in Gibbs free energy *is* zero for a reversible process (as long as no non-PV work is being done).  The equivalence that you provide, $\Delta H = q = T \Delta S$, is only valid for reversible processes at constant $T$ and $P$.  If the process is irreversible then $T \Delta S \neq q$, and thus $\Delta G \neq 0$.